# Most common or acceptable way(s) to say you scored a goal in sports

Tags: word-choice, technical-terminology

I’m curious about the common terminology for scoring goals in sports.

If I had just played a soccer game and I had scored three goals, I would communicate this in English by using *to score the goal* or *to score the point:*

> I scored three goals today.
>
> I scored three points today.

I suppose I *might* use the verb *to make* instead:

> I made three points today.
>
> I made three goals today.

…but probably not. Although those would almost certainly get the point across, it would sound a little odd/awkward as compared with *to score.*

What **verb/noun** combination would be most commonly used to communicate this in German? *Das Tor erzielen?*

> Heute ich habe drei Tore erzielt.
>
> Ich erzielte heute drei Tore.

Or would you be more likely to use *das Tor punkten* or *das Tor schießen* or even *den Punkt machen* or *den Punkt schießen* or *den Punkt erzielen?*

I’m curious about which terminology is most likely to be used or which is at least acceptable. If there are multiple terms or combinations of terms in common use, I’m interested to know that too.

Comment: I think "ein Treffer" could also fit depending on the sport it refers to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im Fußball werden Tore geschossen. Etwas simpler ausgedrückt ist 'Tore machen', etwas elaborierter 'Tore erzielen'. Dann gibt es noch die spezifischeren Ausdrücke wie ein Tor zu köpfen, den Ball hineinzustochern, den Ball ins Tor dribbeln usw. aber schießen ist die allgemein gebräuchliche Form.

Gepunktet wird im Fußball, wenn es kein KO-Wettbewerb ist, bei dem einfach der Sieger weiterkommt, dadurch, dass man mehr Tore erzielt als der Gegner, oder mindestens so viele wie dieser - dann gibt es einen Punkt. Man kann 3 Tore schießen ohne zu punkten, weil der Gegner 4 geschossen hat.

Punkten kann nur die Mannschaft, in dem sie in der Endabrechnung 1 oder 3 Punkte für ein Remis oder einen Sieg bekommt. Vor ca. 20 Jahren gab es für einen Sieg allerdings nur 2 Punkte.

Comment: The answer should be in English because the question is in English (compare http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/1048/). Also, in my opinion, the question mentions soccer only as an _example_, but asks about sports in general, so the answer feels a bit too narrow to me.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu: Dort kannst Du auch meine Meinung dazu nachlesen.

Comment: OP here, I found the specificity of this answer extremely helpful. That's the kind of info I intended to fish for with the wording of my question. As for the answer being in a different language than the question: Well, I know this decision isn't entirely up to me (since other users will come along later and benefit from this Q/A, and their needs/desires count too), but I personally appreciated the answer being in german. That aspect provided additional context and confirmation of how these ideas are expressed *in German*.

Comment: Congrats, you interpreted OP correctly. Thank god he cleared that up quickly, before any kind of discussion could start. :) As for the language: you failed to gather enough support in the meta thread for your opinion to be even close to consensus, so please don't use it as justification. Thanks :)

Comment: Schlechter Verlierer? Von einer Justifikation war nie die Rede, sondern nur von meiner Meinung.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the sport, especially how goals (or rather points) are counted, what the physical goals look like and how the ball (or puck or whatever) is moved into it. The most generic translation of *goal* would be *Ziel* (can also mean ‘target’ or ‘finish’) and *er**ziel**en* can be used with both, *Punkt* and *Tor* in almost any sport as applicable. Less formally, ***machen*** is possible with both, too.

A *Tor* is a rectangular target limited by posts and crossbars, often with a net attached. They are used in all kinds of hockey, handball, football and polo. If the ball is kicked with a foot or hit with a stick towards the goal, one can use ***schießen*** ‘shoot’. In handball or water polo, where the ball is moved with the hands, one would rather use ***werfen*** ‘throw’. 
In basketball, one can *werfen* a *Korb* ‘basket’, but since they are good for 1 through 3 points each, which determine the result, it’s more common to say how many *Punkte* ‘points’ someone *erzielt* ‘scored’. 
In American football and rugby, I think, goals play a minor part in scores, so *Punkte erzielen* or maybe *… holen* is again more appropriate.

Comment: Punkt wird im Fußball nicht verwendet. Ein Punkt kann das Resultat eines Spiels sein, das unentschieden endet, ob 0:0 oder 4:4. Auch Ziele werden im Fußball nicht gemacht oder erzielt - man macht oder schießt ein Tor, als gewählter Ausdruck ist auch ein Tor erzielen möglich. Im Handball ist m.W. schießen auch nicht falsch, aber werfen wohl üblicher.

Answer (score 2):

You're not far off.

As far as a higher-level text like in a news report is concerned, the combination of `erzielen` and `Tor` would be a safe bet. The examples you gave, corrected for grammar and context, would thus be good ones:

> Der FC Hinterhuzelhausen *erzielte* am Abend *drei Tore* gegen Dynamo Dreibein.

Another good combination for such a context is `erspielen` and `Punkt`.

> Im Topspiel SV Möhringen gegen den BV Banane *erspielte* die Heimmannschaft *vierzehn Punkte* durch zwei Touchdowns.

As for personal speech, like when recounting your performance in today's match to your friends, you'd use less "noble" combinations like `machen` and `Tore`/`Punkte` or `schießen` and `Tore`.

> Ich habe heute *keine Tore gemacht* #sadface :( :( :(
>
> Karlssons Franz hat sich gestern selbst übertroffen und mit seinen *vier geschossenen Toren* wieder zu seiner alten Form zurückgefunden.

All these are easily understood and often seen and heard. And even those combinations I put in the "personal use" section would not be frowned upon when reading a news paper. Via Google, I found these combinations in the national press, like Focus and Spiegel, too.

Comment: Die Antwort ist falsch. In allen gängigen Wettbewerben werden pro Spiel maximal 3 Punkte vergeben und zwar dafür, mehr Tore geschossen zu haben als der Gegner, einen Punkt gibt es für ein Unentschieden, dass auch durch ein 0:0 zustande kommen kann, ohne dass ein Tor geschossen wurde. Ein erspieltes Tor wird auch jeder als einen Gegensatz zu einem Tor aus einer Standardsitutation mit ruhendem Ball auffassen, etwa einem Elfmeter oder direkten Freistoß. Man schießt Tore, macht Tore, oder erzielt Tore.

Comment: @user so, Antwort neutralisiert, völlig irrelevante Fußball-Spezifika rausgeworfen.

Comment: Tja - um so schlimmer!

Comment: Der Fokus auf Fußball liegt aber schon in der Frage.

Comment: @user seh ich nicht so. Fußball wird nur einmal als Beispiel erwähnt. Im Rest der Frage geht's um "sports". Es gibt bedeutend mehr Sportarten als Fußball in denen man Punkte oder Tore erspielen kann. Auch in Deutschland.

Comment: Beim Eiskunstlauf, Tennis, Biathlon und vielen weiteren Sportarten werden keine Tore geschossen. Die Frage war ja doch, ob man Tore punkten kann bzw. ob Punkte und Tore zu schießen/zu machen gleichbedeutend benutzt werden kann.